# How to remove NULL/Unwanted values from SQL queries within the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

The result from this query is naturally grouping unwanted 'groups'. ie there are NULL and ? values within the data that i do not want to be used as groups. How do i exclude these kinds of values?

code below

```
SELECT 
    age, primary_fur_colour, location,
    SUM(CASE WHEN running = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_running,
    SUM(CASE WHEN chasing = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_chasing,
    SUM(CASE WHEN climbing = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_climbing,
    SUM(CASE WHEN eating = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_eating,
    SUM(CASE WHEN foraging = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_foraging
FROM squirrel_data
GROUP BY age, primary_fur_colour, location
```

the output is as follows

| age | primary_fur_colour | location | total_running | total_chasing | total_climbing | total_eating | total_foraging |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ? | Gray | Above Ground | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Gray | Above Ground | 5 | 8 | 11 | 4 | 4 |
|  | Cinnamon | Ground Plane | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| Adult | Cinnamon | Ground Plane | 68 | 15 | 23 | 70 | 165 |
| Adult |  | Ground Plane | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Juvenile | Cinnamon | Ground Plane | 13 | 3 | 4 | 16 | 14 |
| ? | Gray | Ground Plane | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|  | Black | Ground Plane | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Adult | Black | Above Ground | 6 | 0 | 19 | 2 | 4 |
| Juvenile | Gray | Above Ground | 13 | 13 | 56 | 22 | 17 |

Comment: Not tested: `... where  coalesce(age, '0') not in('?', '0')  or location is not null`.

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause? `WHERE age <> '?' AND primary_fur_colour <> '?' AND location <> '?'`. (This excludes NULLs, too,because NULL is never equal or unequal to any value.)

Comment: Use a `where` to ignore them or a `case`/`coalesce()` to assign to another group. You might want to trade all those conditionals sums for a regular aggregate `filter` clause: `count(*)filter(where running='True')`. If you're only holding `null`, `true` and `false` in those columns, you can change their type to a proper `boolean`: `alter table squirrel_data alter column running type boolean using (running::bool);` - they will be lighter as well as faster and more convenient to use.

Comment: Zegarek, I will explore further data types. Current data type is boolean and the FILTER query was not counting True values therefore i resorted to SUM (CASE)

Comment: Oops that should have been: `...or primary_fur_colour is not null`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to trade all those conditional sums for a regular aggregate [`filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). If they are type `boolean`, you can use them directly, without comparing to a `'True'`.

Use a `where` to skip unwanted groups: a [`not in`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-NOT-IN) can handle them all at once, including `null`s.

```sql
SELECT 
    age, primary_fur_colour, location,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE running  ) AS total_running,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE chasing  ) AS total_chasing,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE climbing ) AS total_climbing,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE eating   ) AS total_eating,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE foraging ) AS total_foraging
FROM squirrel_data
WHERE '?' NOT IN (age::text,
                  primary_fur_colour::text,
                  location::text )
GROUP BY age, primary_fur_colour, location;
```

Or use [conditional expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CONDITIONAL) to reassign to another (default) group.

```sql
SELECT 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(age,'?'),               'Adult'       ) as age, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(primary_fur_colour,'?'),'Gray'        ) as primary_fur_colour, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(location,'?'),          'Ground Plane') as location,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE running  ) AS total_running,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE chasing  ) AS total_chasing,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE climbing ) AS total_climbing,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE eating   ) AS total_eating,
    COUNT(*)FILTER(WHERE foraging ) AS total_foraging
FROM squirrel_data
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```